# How to move this div block?

Tags: html, css

I can't seem to find any  information on how to move .six to the left top corner. I've tried searching on Google, YouTube, etc.

Here's my code:

```css
.plat {
  background-color: grey;
  width: 20%;
  border: 3px solid red;
  margin-left: -0.5%;
}

.duck {
  background-color: blue;
  color: yellow;
  border: solid 3px red;
  margin-left: 20%;
  width: 20%;
}

.bill {
  background-color: green;
  width: 20%;
  margin-left: 40%;
  border: solid 3px red;
}

.dan {
  background-color: yellow;
  border: 3px solid red;
  width: 20%;
  margin-left: 60%;
  text-align: center;
}

p {
  line-height: 3px;
}

.five {
  background-color: purple;
  width: 20%;
  border: red solid 3px;
  margin-left: 80%;
}

.six {
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  border: 3px solid red;
  width: 20%;
  margin-left: 80%;
  margin-bottom: 500px;
}

.seven {
  background-color: blue;
  border: 3px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div class="plat">

  <p>apple</p>
  <p>pie</p>
  <p>cheese</p>
</div>

<div class="duck">
  <p>apple</p>
  <p>pie</p>
  <p>cheese</p>

</div>

<div class="bill">
  <p>apple</p>
  <p>pie</p>
  <p>cheese</p>
</div>

<div class="dan">
  <p>apple</p>
  <p>pie</p>
  <p>cheese</p>
</div>

<div class="five">
  <p>apple</p>
  <p>pie</p>
  <p>cheese</p>
</div>

<div class="six">

  <p>apple</p>
  <p>pie</p>
  <p>cheese</p>

</div>

<div class="seven">
  <p>apple</p>
  <p>pie</p>
  <p>cheese</p>
</div>

<div class="eight">
  <p>apple</p>
  <p>pie</p>
  <p>cheese</p>
</div>
```

What I'm trying to do is moving my .six div to the top right corner, but I can't get it to work.

Comment: It might be helpful to describe where your ".six" <div/> appears, and give a minimal version of your CSS+HTML that concentrates on just these elements of your source-code.

Answer (score 0):

Here, black `.six` in the top right corner.

```css
.plat {
  background-color: grey;
  width: 20%;
  border: 3px solid red;
  margin-left: -0.5%;
}

.duck {
  background-color: blue;
  color: yellow;
  border: solid 3px red;
  margin-left: 20%;
  width: 20%;
}

.bill {
  background-color: green;
  width: 20%;
  margin-left: 40%;
  border: solid 3px red;
}

.dan {
  background-color: yellow;
  border: 3px solid red;
  width: 20%;
  margin-left: 60%;
  text-align: center;
}

p {
  line-height: 3px;
}

.five {
  background-color: purple;
  width: 20%;
  border: red solid 3px;
  margin-left: 80%;
}

.six {
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  border: 3px solid red;
  width: 20%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
}

.seven {
  background-color: blue;
  border: 3px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div class="plat">

  <p>apple</p>
  <p>pie</p>
  <p>cheese</p>
</div>

<div class="duck">
  <p>apple</p>
  <p>pie</p>
  <p>cheese</p>

</div>

<div class="bill">
  <p>apple</p>
  <p>pie</p>
  <p>cheese</p>
</div>

<div class="dan">
  <p>apple</p>
  <p>pie</p>
  <p>cheese</p>
</div>

<div class="five">
  <p>apple</p>
  <p>pie</p>
  <p>cheese</p>
</div>

<div class="six">

  <p>apple</p>
  <p>pie</p>
  <p>cheese</p>

</div>

<div class="seven">
  <p>apple</p>
  <p>pie</p>
  <p>cheese</p>
</div>

<div class="eight">
  <p>apple</p>
  <p>pie</p>
  <p>cheese</p>
</div>
```

Comment: position absolute is destructive , if he could re arrange his html it will be better

Comment: The OP didn't specify anything but positioning in the top right corner.

Comment: i know but it a bad practice

Answer (score 0):

it's very simple 
change the .six class

```
.six {background-color:black;
                color:white;
                border: 3px solid red;
                position: absolute;
                top: 0%;
                right: 0%;
                width:20%;
                margin-left:80%;
                margin-bottom:500px;
                }
```

i hope this help you.